# Multiple variables in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to make my URL become from this: 
`www.mysite.com/index.php?area=test1&par=test2` 
to this: 
`www.mysite.com/test1/test2`

my .htaccess look like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*?)/?$ /index.php?area=$1 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

i get only the area variable, and dont know how to continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply pass all to php like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

than process it in php

```
var_dump($_SERVER);//parse all info you want
```

Comment: cant understand what that doing